# Scaling a variable multiplied by power series is not giving expected output

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, series-expansion, variable

I have a power series getting multiplied by a variable, which gets scaled by the small parameter used in the power series. As an example, in the following dummy series:

```
x^2 (y'[x]+O[\[Epsilon]])
```

I am trying to replace `x` by `\[Epsilon] z`. The expected output is `\[Epsilon] z^2 Y'[z] + O[\[Epsilon]]^3`. Naively, I tried

```
x^2 (y'[x]+O[\[Epsilon]]) /. {y->(Y[#/\[Epsilon]]&), x->\[Epsilon] z}
```

But this just absorbed everything into `O[\[Epsilon]]`. I suspect the product `x^2 O[\[Epsilon]]` is messing up. Now, I can individually replace `x` in both terms and multiply the result, but that makes my original problem messy. Is there a cleaner/correct way to do this kind of operation?

P.S. I am a beginner in Mathematica.

Comment: I would recommend doing the replacement before the series expansion or use `Normal` to retain the leading-order term, do the replacement, and then if necessary add the estimated `O[\[Epsilon]]^3` to the result. The problem is naive replacements(including `\[Epsilon]`) in a `SeriesData` object is that it is no longer guaranteed to be a proper power series including all relevant terms to the specified order,

Comment: @N0va, thanks for the suggestion. I just thought of a neat trick: replacing `x` by `\[Epsilon]^a z`, and then setting `a` to 1 in the end. Since `a` is not specified during the variable change, Mathematica doesn't absorb it in the trailing term. There's probably a better way to handle this, but this trick seems to work exactly how I wanted and I am happy with that.